# concatenate string in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a variable `dItemDesc` defined in the Group Footer:

```
whilereadingrecords;
stringvar DispItemDesc;
DispItemDesc := DispItemDesc + "> " + {Command.ItemDesc}
```

The display for the first record is correct, but following records just continue to concatenate the string.  Where / how would I reset the variable to blank?

Answer (score 0):

Create another formula as a reset. Place it at the stage you'd like it to clear out. (Presumably one section below the current Group Footer, or in the Group Header.)

```
whilereadingrecords;
stringvar DispItemDesc;
DispItemDesc := ""
```

Comment: No need for 'shared' designation for the variable. Shared designation is needed only when subreports are involved.